# How to prevent object should not be slice

Tags: c#

I have a 2 classes one is base class and second is derived class. 
Want to restrict object slicing, how can I do it using C#.net ?

Comment: Can you give us some more info? e.g. with some code examples what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean the `sealed` keyword to prevent derived classes to overwritte some methods or an entire class? (see [sealed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Comment: I want to know, can we prevent object slicing in .net ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about slicing in C#. See this very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/536267/944681)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

My initial thoughts as described below were found as not true:
See: [C++ slicing in Java / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536267/c-slicing-in-java-c-sharp/536290#536290)

---

**Original Answer:**

If I understood correctly this is a theoretical question.
`REDUCING` slicing can be done by not defining new members in the derived class.

slicing occurs when assigning an instance of a derived class to a base class reference type.
In this case the system does not know where to allocate a new data-type because it is defined in the derived class only and not in the base class.

But there is no way to `RESTRICT` that, this is what suppose to happen and it is defined as

> A natural and unavoidable consequence of assignment by value from
>   subclass objects

[Object slicing - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

however you can declare a class as `sealed` to prevent inheritance that will restrict object slicing because it will prevent the cause (Inheritance) so you will not have a derived class to assign to a base reference by value.

Comment: the link you provided deals with C++, not C#. The question asks about slicing in C#

Comment: True, but the concept of object slicing is theoretical and language agnostic. every language that can provide a value-type structured memory stream e.g. structs or classes will deal with the issue called object-slicing.

Comment: not according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/536290/238902)

Comment: every day you learn some thing new... :)